# How can I use Twilio queues without agents having to dial in?

Tags: twilio

I'd like to have a support queue and a sales queue that call an available agent when there's someone in the queue. The way queue functionality is described in the Twilio docs, it seems that the only way to connect an agent and a caller is to have the agent call into the queue. Well, that's no good for a queue that would be empty for most of the time -- how would they know when to dial in?

Is there a way for an agent to be called and then connected to the queue when someone is waiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is the exact use case for the [Twilio TaskRouter API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter). From the docs:

> Twilio TaskRouter is a system for distributing tasks such as phone calls, leads, support tickets, and other work items to the people and processes that can best handle them. Example applications for TaskRouter include:
>
> - Distributing calls to call center agents. TaskRouter supports common features required in call center environments, such as skills-based routing and task prioritization.
> - Prioritizing and assigning CRM cases to agents in order to make sure they're handled within service level. TaskRouter lets you specify overflow rules for tasks, allowing you to vary assignment rules based on time spent in queue and case content.
> - Distributing leads to inside sales teams. TaskRouter's business rules allow you to control prioritization so that your team is always working on the most important opportunity.

Check out the [quickstart guide for TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/taskrouter) which takes you through creating a workspace and workers and creating tasks for the workers from phone calls.